# Is "Organization" schema recognized by Google?

Tags: schema, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

Google doesn't support organization schema as far as I have seen. Local Business schema works but organiozation schema is just recognized as local business schema for some of the examples on schema.org that I checked.
Please help if anyone has an idea about this.

Wrote a code for the organization with all the necessary properties and there is no error in the code when I checked the code in Rich Results Test but it gets recognized as logos schema. If I remove the link to logo then no schema is detected.

Comment: So you've kind of answered your own question. Organization with a logo is a rich result supported by Google. Note that LoacalBusiness is a type of Organization, so you can also use that to provide the logo.

Comment: Yeah but the business is not local by any definition. So I can't really create a local business schema for that and creating an organization schema is pointless, right?

Comment: No Organization is valid for the Logo feature. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/logo